# How to include a div in table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm going to put a `div` inside a `table` tag but it doesn't work.

```
<table>
<div id="account" style="border: 1px solid red;">
    <tr>
        <td>ایمیل قبلی:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="oldmail" /></td>

        <td>ایمیل جدید:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="newmail" /></td>

        <td>ایمیل تایید:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="newmail2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>پسورد قبلی:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="oldpass" /></td>

        <td>پسورد جدید:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="newpass" /></td>

        <td>پسورد تایید:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="newpass2" /></td>
    </tr>
</div>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uJSuR/

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why do you need a div in the table? just put account id on the table tag.

Comment: If you want to just set border for those rows you need to define `style` for each `tr` tags otherwise just put the id for the table.

Comment: No , This is not all if the code. Complete code has some more divs and ... So I'm going to jQuery the table.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/uJSuR/1/

```
<table id="account" style="border: 1px solid red;">
    <tr>
        <td>ایمیل قبلی:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="oldmail" /></td>

        <td>ایمیل جدید:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="newmail" /></td>

        <td>ایمیل تایید:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="newmail2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>پسورد قبلی:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="oldpass" /></td>

        <td>پسورد جدید:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="newpass" /></td>

        <td>پسورد تایید:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="newpass2" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

or put your styles on the `tr`, It's a little unclear on what you're trying to accomplish.

```
tr {
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [The CSS table model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display)

Here are the equivalent Html elements to css properties (from the above w3.org link)

```
table    { display: table }
tr       { display: table-row }
thead    { display: table-header-group }
tbody    { display: table-row-group }
tfoot    { display: table-footer-group }
col      { display: table-column }
colgroup { display: table-column-group }
td, th   { display: table-cell }
caption  { display: table-caption }
```

Comment: maybe you didn't do it right.. could you post the code that you tries in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Actually after some searches I knew I should change `div` tag to `tbody` tag.
thank you for your answers.

Answer (score -1):

You might want something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr id="account" style="border: 1px solid red;">
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>ایمیل قبلی:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="oldmail" /></td>
          <td>ایمیل جدید:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="newmail" /></td>
          <td>ایمیل تایید:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="newmail2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>پسورد قبلی:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="oldpass" /></td>

          <td>پسورد جدید:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="newpass" /></td>

          <td>پسورد تایید:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="newpass2" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `<tr>` can only contain `<th>` or `<td>`, not `<table>`. And you should always avoid nesting tables imo (not my vote btw)

Comment: @PeterVR `<tr>` tag was my mistake! I forgot to put a `<td>`.